# Currying and reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript, reduce, currying

Why at first I get 80 then 88 and then 90? Can anyone explain in detail what is happening in the `compose` function?

```js
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));


const sum = a => b => a + b
const multiply = a => b => a * b

const addTransactionFee = sum(2)
const addTax = multiply(1.1)
const addMonthlyPromotion = multiply(0.8)
const log = a => {
  console.log(a)
  return a
}

const paymentAmount = compose(
  log,
  addTransactionFee, 
  log,
  addTax,
  log,
  addMonthlyPromotion
)(100)
```

Comment: `addMonthlyPromotion(100) = 100 * 8 = 80`; `addTax(80) = 80 * 1.1 = 88`; `addTransactionFee(88) = 88 + 2 = 90`;

Comment: That `compose(log,addTransactionFee,log,addTax,log,addMonthlyPromotion)(100)` reduce to `log(addTransactionFee(log(addTax(log(addMonthlyPromotion(100))))))`

Comment: @RickyMo  how the  `reduce` method arranged these functions in that way

Comment: You can study the behavior of [Array.reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion instead. This way the order of functions is preserved (and not reversed).

```js
const recursion = (value, func, ...fns) =>
  func ? recursion(func(value), ...fns) : value;

const paymentAmount = (amount) =>
  recursion(
    amount,
    log,
    addTransactionFee,
    log,
    addTax,
    log,
    addMonthlyPromotion,
    log
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The compose function with the loop of reduce..take the right function (the latest (`addMonthlyPromotion()`)) and make the result of 100 * 0.8 so you have 80 at the first loop.
Then you have the second loop with the second function (`addTax()`) it multiply's the previous result of (80) with 1.1 so 88.
And the final loop and the 3rd one of reduce with the function (`addTransactionFee()`) add 2 in your previous number so 90.

Now the compose function goes from right to left of looped function and do the calculations.

Comment: i know that when reduce method loop through an array,    it takes the first one comes to action, then why in this situation the last one comes to action?

Comment: because of the function composition
compose(addTransactionFee,addTax,addMonthlyPromotion) with that it takes the last function first then goes from right to left until it finished.
is it clear ? :)

Comment: if for example in the const paymentAmmout = compose(addMonthlyPromotion , addTransactionFee , addTax)(100)..you will have entire another result.
the first function excecution will be addTax() second excecution addTransactionFee() and the final will be the addMonthlyPromotion(). And of course the final number will be not 90.